# C++ VS: 'new' and 'delete' override in the multi-DLL solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a large solution, every project in which generates a dll. In one of them I've put 'new' and 'delete' overrides, but as it seems, they aren't overriding the standard allocator in other dlls. Is it normal? Are those overrides local with respect to dll?

As a solution I can write wrapping functions-allocators — 'my_new' and 'my_delete', which will work in any way I want, and use them instead of 'new'/'delete'. But I'd like to know, what happens with the overrides outside the their local dll.

Thanks)

Comment: `But I'd like to know, what happens with the overrides outside the their local dll.`  The overrides are applicable to their local dll only; so in essence the answer is "what overrides?"

Comment: Do you link these other dlls against your dll that overrides them?

Comment: @UKMonkey, only for local use? Alright, thank you)

Comment: @n.m., didn't get it. I haven't worked with dlls much before, so I'm quite ignorant in here. What do you mean by 'link against'? The projects are dependent on that memory dll project, if you mean this

Comment: Is your overriding dll a *link* dependency of all other dlls? When you open your other dll in a dependency walker, do you see your overriding dll?

Comment: @n.m. yes, they are linked against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overrides are local and safe when used inside of a single DLL. They are independent executables after all. But you may run into a scenario when an object created in the DLL with overloads is passed to a function defined in another DLL where it is eventually destroyed through the standard operator delete. (It applies also to the reversed direction.) This will lead to an undefined behavior which is usually a crash.

After all, a general rule when programming for Windows is to create and destroy object by the code from the same DLL. So to be safe you should verify that all your DLLs respect this rule.

Comment: What about those wrapper allocators? Any object in any dll would be created and destroyed by them, that's OK, I believe?

Comment: @master_clown, Yes you could create your own specific functions handling new and delete in one DLL for being used by all other DLLs in your solution. Assuming you have total control over those projects and you are able to enforce that pattern.

Comment: perfect) Thank you